# Servlet and jsp

Tags: jsp

How to call servlet program using HTML.

Comment: explain more what exactly you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

web.xml should be

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.testServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/testServlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

your html code should be

```
<html>
<FORM METHOD=GET ACTION="com/testServlet">
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are a way of generating and serving HTML files (among other things).  You could link to (`<a href...>`) or reference (e.g. `<iframe>`) a servlet in HTML.  You could also submit a form, or make a AJAX request, to the servlet.  If you say what you're trying to accomplish, we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

Place a link or form whose target is the servlet url. It's invoked through the user clicking or submission of forms.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common ways is to make an HTML form and set its target as per the url pattern set in servlet-mapping tag in web.xml